# Angular event bindings as custom attributes in Emmet

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, emmet

I would like to add angular event bindings via Emmet but don't know how to do it, or if it's even possible. Simply treating them as normal custom attributes (with parentheses added around them) does not work. That is, I hoped the following would work, but it doesn't

```
button[(click)] ---Emmet---> <button (click)=""></button>
```

I realize that I could probably just use the following:

```
button[on-click] ---Emmet---> <button on-click=""></button>
```

but I prefer the other style. I also realize that I could create my own custom snippets to achieve this, but I'm currently very happy using VS Code as my IDE, and they have certain limits on what kind of custom snippets you can add, as seen in their [Emmet documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet). In fact, my primary reason for wanting this is actually so I can add my own custom snippets and abbreviations for Ionic in VS Code, such as:

```
{
   "html": {        
       "snippets": {
           "ibtn|ion-button": "btn[ion-button. (click)]"
       }        
   }`
```

}

and get the following Emmet functionality

```
ibtn ---Emmet---> <button ion-button (click)=""></button>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.